# Exclude directory from htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create a restricted area on a subdirectory, but there is some conflict with the htaccess auto generated from WorPdress on home page and so I got a redirect on 404 error page when I try to access on this subdirectory

I tried to exclude it from `.htaccess` on home page with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(folder1|folder2|folder3) [NC]
```

but nothing. How can I solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Where are you putting your Condition?

Answer (score 1):

You should modify WP htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder1/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder2/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder3/$

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Changing the `.htaccess` file is bad practice in my opinion. Themes break when switching. Changing permalink settings and some themes can delete the file. You should use `add_rewrite_rule` [API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule)

Comment: There is no diffrence between your rule and op's rule?